# Can I use Sharp Architecture in an classic ASP.Net application or it is only for ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, architecture, sharp-architecture

I want to start a new project that use NHibernate as data access layer. Now my question is that, Can I use Sharp Architecture in an ASP.Net application or it is only for ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is not your question, but just to be sure: you can use NHibernate *without* using S#arp Architecture.
And, in that case, there's absolutely no problem on using NH with a WebForm application.

Now, getting back to S#arp. I've never used S#arp, but [reading their tutorial](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/wiki/Simple-crud-application) you can see the  the interaction between Controller and View is based on the domain model.
That is, S#arp usage is between the Controller and your backend architecture. So, if you're on a WebForms app, the codebehind will do the Controller role.

So, as far as I can understand by now, yes, you can use S#arp with a WebForms app.

Regards